# Plaid Transaction Webhooks Not Firing When Using React Plaid Link

Tags: reactjs, plaid

I am using ReactPlaidLink to build an app that retrieves users transaction history and displays it on the front end. My goal right now is to get the webhooks to fire at the specified endpoint. I set up an endpoint to listen for requests using both webhook.site and requestbin, and have not seen a request come through. I have specified the endpoint in both the React-Plaid. From what I understand form the documentation, specifying a webhook paramater is all that's necessary for the webhooks to fire to the right endpoint. I am definitely a novice when it comes to webhooks, I hope I'm not missing something super obvious. Would appreciate any insight you can offer.

````
<PlaidLinkButton
           buttonProps={{
             className:
               "btn btn-large waves-effect waves-light hoverable blue accent-3 main-btn"
           }}
           plaidLinkProps={{
             clientName: "BankLinker",
             key:" ",
             token: "my-token",
             env: "sandbox",
             product: ["transactions"],
             webhook: 'https://webhook.site/465538a7-f2a5-4d55-b017-db23b949ef91',
             onSuccess: this.handleOnSuccess,
           }}
           onScriptLoad={() => this.setState({ loaded: true })}
         >
           Add Account
         </PlaidLinkButton>```

and HandleSuccess


```handleOnSuccess = (token, metadata) => {
   const { accounts } = this.props;
   const plaidData = {
     public_token: token,
     metadata: metadata,
     accounts: accounts,
     // webhook: "https://webhook.site/465538a7-f2a5-4d55-b017-db23b949ef91",

   };
this.props.addAccount(plaidData);

 };
````

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on the RN SDK, but on a quick glance I don't see anything glaringly, obviously wrong here.  Can you confirm that you can go through the Link flow, wait a few seconds, and then call the /transactions/get endpoint, and successfully get data back from it?  That will help confirm that the issue is with webhooks and not some other part of the process.